# Best way to join two tables one to three possible columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to join two tables by string id but the second table has 3 possible id columns to join.
Tried to go with 'or' but the request is really slow and creating a view with 3 copies of the table isn't good anyway either and I don't know how to put all values in one set so the view don't has 3 copies of all needed fields.
Is there any  better possibility? How can I join 2 tables having only one copy of fields from second table.

```
Table1
ID DocumentID Value
1  Doc123     54
2  Doxx24     85
3  Doxx24     111
4  Docodoc1   90

Table2
ID2 Document1ID Document2ID Document3ID Value
1  Doc123       null       null        54
2  null         Doxx24     null        85
3  null         Doxx24     null        111
4  null         null       Docodoc1    90

Output
ID DocumentID Value ID2 Document1ID Document2ID Document3ID Value
1  Doc123     54    1  Doc123       null       null        54
2  Doxx24     85    2  null         Doxx24     null        85
3  Doxx24     111   3  null         Doxx24     null        111
4  Docodoc1   90    4  null         null       Docodoc1    90
```

As you can see the value I need to join is in 3 columns but all columns share the same data the difference is the document type that is nowhere described just other than column name. Table1.DocumentID contains one value from the three DocumentID's from Table2 and I need all the data from table2 if it match.

This is my whole query.

```
SELECT ledger.ACCOUNTINGDATE, ledger.DOCUMENTNUMBER, ledger.JOURNALNUMBER, ledger.SUBLEDGERVOUCHER, ledger.ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT, ledger.GENERALJOURNALENTRY, ledger.MAINACCOUNTVALUE, 
              ledger.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYCODE, ledger.TRANSACTIONCURRENCYAMOUNT, ledger.Typ_Ksiegowania, ledger.Typ_Transakcji, ledger.JOURNALCATEGORY, ledger.LEDGERACCOUNT, ledger.REPORTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT, 
              ledger.RECID AS ledgerREcid, ledger.CREATEDTRANSACTIONID, ledger.MAINACCOUNTNAME, ledger.PARTITION, trans.ITEMID, trans.VOUCHERPHYSICAL, trans.VOUCHER, trans.RECID, trans.REFERENCEID, trans.SettelemntVoucher, 
              trans.COSTAMOUNTPHYSICAL, trans.COSTAMOUNTPOSTED, trans.PACKINGSLIPID, trans.QTY, trans.INVENTTRANSID, trans.CURRENCYCODE, trans.INVOICEID, row_number() over (order by ledger.partition) as MyKey
FROM     dbo.TestGeneralTransYear AS ledger LEFT OUTER JOIN
              dbo.SRM_InventTransSettlementTab AS trans ON (ledger.SUBLEDGERVOUCHER = trans.VOUCHER COLLATE Polish_CI_AS or ledger.SUBLEDGERVOUCHER = trans.voucherphysical  COLLATE Polish_CI_AS or ledger.SUBLEDGERVOUCHER = trans.SettelemntVoucher COLLATE Polish_CI_AS)
```

Comment: Absolutely no idea based on the lack of information provided. Show us the table definitions and some sample data so we can make sense of what you are asking.

Comment: looks like "UNION ALL"-approach can be used. Please provide some sample data and desired output

Comment: Please also show your attempt using `OR`

Comment: Except your query doesn't match your sample data, so as part of creating a [mre] you need to ensure your sample query is consistent with your sample data.

Comment: And it seems your question isn't "HOW" to join them - since you seem to have accomplished that, but rather how to improve the performance? In which case as already commented try a `UNION ALL` approach.

Comment: Tried to give the most essential data. I don't think giving all the fields of my view would help here the only change is that along witch excact name field before I actually added the query. Yes I did accomplised it but the quesry is so slow it breaks SSMS of out memory.

Comment: I tried with just 'union' didn't see better performance. I'll try with union all. Both tables have at this moment 25 mln records and they grow like 10mln per year.

Comment: Yeah, `UNION` performance is crap, thats why we said `UNION ALL` - `UNION` attempts to de-duplicate the results which frequently results in poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a COALESCE approach...

```
SELECT *
FROM   Table1 AS T1
       JOIN Table2 AS T2
          ON T1.Document_Id = COALESCE(T2.Document1ID, T2.Document2ID, T3.Document3ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the fastest would be not to make 3 views on table 2.

```
create view Table2_view1 as select Document1ID as ID, * where Document1ID is not null
create view Table2_view2 as select Document2ID as ID, * where Document2ID is not null
create view Table2_view3 as select Document3ID as ID, * where Document3ID is not null
```

then do it as 3 UNIONS and joins

```
select * from Table1 join Table2_view1
union
select * from Table1 join Table2_view2
```

My guess is SQL Server would be good at interpreting this fast.